# picokernel library for msp430

Tags: c, microcontroller, freertos, msp430, rtos

Recently I interested in rtos applications and I wanted to use one of them. However, I read that msp430g2553 has quite small memory thats why freertos cannot be used with this (maybe I m wrong). then I found a library for rtos that usable with msp430g2553 which is : https://github.com/npatel33/picokernel-MSP430 but I coundnt add this library to CCS.

I tried to add these kernel.c and kernel.h but while building those I got errors like :

```
type here
**** Build of configuration Release for project blink_rtos ****

"D:\\CCS\\ccs\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k -j 8 all -O 
 
Building file: "../kernel.c"
Invoking: MSP430 Compiler
"D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/bin/cl430" -vmsp -O2 --use_hw_mpy=none --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/Users/enesy/Desktop/CCS workplace/blink_rtos" --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/include" --advice:power=all --define=__MSP430G2553__ --printf_support=minimal --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="kernel.d_raw"  "../kernel.c"
 
>> Compilation failure
subdir_rules.mk:9: recipe for target 'kernel.obj' failed
"../kernel.c", line 58: warning #225-D: function "__nop" declared implicitly
"../kernel.c", line 82: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 90: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 103: warning #1493-D: GCC-style explicit register variables are not supported
"../kernel.c", line 112: warning #1493-D: GCC-style explicit register variables are not supported
"../kernel.c", line 113: warning #1493-D: GCC-style explicit register variables are not supported
"../kernel.c", line 114: warning #1493-D: GCC-style explicit register variables are not supported
"../kernel.c", line 127: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 133: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 134: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 145: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 121: remark #1533-D: (ULP 6.1) Detected use of multiplication on a device that has no hardware multiplier
"../kernel.c", line 136: remark #1544-D: (ULP 13.1) Detected loop counting up. Recommend loops count down as detecting zeros is easier
"../kernel.c", line 162: error #18: expected a ")"
"../kernel.c", line 49: remark #1535-D: (ULP 8.1) variable "Counter" is used as a constant. Recommend declaring variable as either 'static const' or 'const'
7 errors detected in the compilation of "../kernel.c".
gmake: *** [kernel.obj] Error 1
Building file: "../main.c"
Invoking: MSP430 Compiler
"D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/bin/cl430" -vmsp -O2 --use_hw_mpy=none --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/Users/enesy/Desktop/CCS workplace/blink_rtos" --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/include" --advice:power=all --define=__MSP430G2553__ --printf_support=minimal --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.d_raw"  "../main.c"
Finished building: "../main.c"
 
Building file: "../example/blink.c"
Invoking: MSP430 Compiler
"D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/bin/cl430" -vmsp -O2 --use_hw_mpy=none --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/Users/enesy/Desktop/CCS workplace/blink_rtos" --include_path="D:/CCS/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS/include" --advice:power=all --define=__MSP430G2553__ --printf_support=minimal --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="example/blink.d_raw" --obj_directory="example"  "../example/blink.c"
Finished building: "../example/blink.c"
 
gmake: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: This commit https://github.com/npatel33/picokernel-MSP430/commit/8b27757697a6ca41a57be749352f21c508517b93 looks relevant to the error messages. So you either need to go before this commit or compile with ti-gcc instead.